# unwrap inner json object using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've got a JSON that looks like this

```
{
    "file": "sample.txt",
    "valid": "true",
    "parameters": {
         "size": "15kb",
         "charset": "UTF-8",
         ....
    }
}
```

But I want to deserialize it as a single object. 
Not like this

```
class ValidatedFile {
    String file;
    boolean valid;
    FileParameters params;
}
```

but like this

```
class ValidatedFile {
    String file;
    boolean valid;
    String size;
    String charset;
    ....
}
```

I need to do some kind of unwrapping of this object.
How to do it using `jackson`?

Comment: whatever parameters you have  written in  FileParameters model class instead of writting there write in ValidatedFile  class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@JsonProperty("parameters")`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.Map;

public class Product {

    String file;
    boolean valid;
    String size;
    String charset;



    @JsonProperty("parameters")
    private void unpackNested(Map<String,Object> parameters) {
        this.size = (String)parameters.get("size");
        this.charset = (String)parameters.get("charset");
    }

}
```

Other [approaches](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values).

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is unnecessary