# Can get field from inner json object with jackson?

Tags: java, jackson

I have `json` like that:

```
{
    "somethingElse": "foobar",
    "snils": {
        "number": "123"
    }
}
```

And class:

```
@Data
public class Documents {
    private String snilsNumber;
    private String somethingElse;
}
```

Can I easily map json to my class with annotation or something else?

Comment: There is `@JsonUnwrapped` but it works directly the other way around: There is this work around which might help: [Whats the Jackson deserialization equivalent of JsonUnwrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570073/whats-the-jackson-deserialization-equivalent-of-jsonunwrapped): **EDIT**: it seems though from the question linked it does work by annotating your `snilsNumber` with `@JsonUnwrapped`

Answer (score 1):

You can use '@JsonRootName'

```
@Data
 @JsonRootName(value = "snils")
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(unknown = true)
 public class Documents {
         private String number;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I've changed the question to be more precise.

Comment: Have you tried i think still this should work @faoxis

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialise it using one extra update method with `JsonProperty` annotation.

```
class Documents {

    private String snilsNumber;
    private String somethingElse;

    @JsonProperty("snils")
    private void unpackSnils(Map<String, Object> brand) {
        this.snilsNumber = (String) brand.get("number");
    }

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

See also:

1. [Jackson nested values](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values)
2. [unwrap inner json object using jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920863/unwrap-inner-json-object-using-jackson)